# How to run an executable (exe) by providing a config file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run an exe in the background by providing a config file (yml in my case)

Tried the below, however this is not pushing the execution to background. -

```
./my.exe start --config-file $my_config_file
```

Found 'start-process' command which are specifically used for this case. With argument list is there any way to send the config file?

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "my.exe" -ArgumentList
```

Comment: Remove the `-Wait` from the `Start-Process` command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `-Wait` argument and pass the process arguments as an array via `-ArgumentList` parameter:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "my.exe" -ArgumentList 'start', '--config-file', "`"$my_config_file`""
```

The strange quoting for `$my_config_file` is required because a path may contain spaces. `Start-Process` does not do automatic quoting. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1#parameters):

> If parameters or parameter values contain a space, they need to be surrounded with escaped double quotes.

Note that you won't receive output of the started process, if that matters to you. You can redirect to a file, using parameters `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError`, but you can't (easily) store the output in a variable.

A way to start a process in the background, while being able to receive its output, is to [create a job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.1).